# Update Lava Iris X1 Grand to Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ota-update

I have Lava Iris X1 Grand. When I first bought it, the update was available. I was not interested at that time. Now I feel it should be installed but it doesn't work.

Anytime I click software update in About phone menu option, it doesn't respond at all. I installed third party app but it says "No update available & your device is already updated".

What to do then?

Comment: I have KitKat now. &want to update to lollipop, I have mentioned in this question. I have used SYSTEM UPDATE app

Answer (score 0):

even I was facing this issue, but some how got the solution by trial and error. The funny part is its very simple. I hope you have downloaded the update package form the link: http://www.lavamobiles.com/support/iris-x1-grand/android-lollipop-upgrade
once you have downloaded it, just rename it from "Update_KK to L_SD card.zip" to "Update.zip", try the steps to update now.

Comment: Renaming the package is not necessary actually. Just remember to put the file in the **root** of SD card.